# Rotate view from anchor swift

Tags: ios, swift3, rotation

In my application, I am calculating BMI of a user based on its height and weight. So based on the BMI value I am animating a needle. The issue is that the needle moves off the center and rotates.

CODE:

```
ivPointer.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)  // i have changed the values still its not working properly
let angle = Double((value * Double.pi)/180)
var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: CGFloat(angle))
```

Comment: With changing the anchor point, your view changes position as well, this is an unfortunate side effect. You should calculate its position change and move it back to where it should be.